# Make CSS image link?

Tags: css, image

Here's my code,

```
  #esc1{ 
  position: absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  right: 0; 
  width: 30px; 
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 30px;
```

My question is can you incorporate a link into this? It's for an image.

Comment: Do you mean click and go to link? Or use a img as background?

Comment: Links are defined in HTML, not CSS. Simply use `<a id="esc1" href="#">...</a>`

Comment: Help? @Reeno I know html, but your code confuses me..

Comment: @DoveMan and why do you sort of curse at people and say that? Because the people that came here did not understand an Unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background: url(path/to/yourimg.png);` to use an image as background.

If you want to make a link to the actual image you can use the HTML **anchor** Tag to wrap your img tag like this

```
<a href="path/to/img">
    <img id="esc1" src="path/to/img" />
</a>
```

But in any case this is trivial. Go to [w3schools](http://http//www.w3schools.com) to learn HTML and CSS

Comment: Not sure, you understand, or maybe I don't. I want the image on the pages effected by this, not a link to the image its-self.

Comment: I want the image (esc1) to be the link to a HTML web page.

Comment: well, that's what @Reno meant in his comment to your question

Comment: I made some edits on my answer. I hope you find them interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100" />
</a>
```

Comment: This isn't what I want.... I want it the the image (esc1) becomes a link on all of the pages it's on. I want to to link to an HTML page.

Comment: @DoveMan Just change the link in `href`. It must be wrapped inside a hyperlink `<a>` tag, the image itself cannot be a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

You write (in a comment to @r1verside's answer):

> I want it the the image (esc1) becomes a link on all of the pages it's
>   on

This is not possible. To have a link, you need an `<a>` tag with a `href` attribute and some content (text or image) between `<a>` and `</a>`. This needs to be done seperately on each page. You *can't* define a link via CSS.